# How to count occurrence of a value in javascript array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects

I'm sure this has been answered ad nauseum, but the answers I'm finding are pretty vague/abstract.

Say I have an array of objects:

```js
const tags = [
  {title: 'fiction'},
  {title: 'non-fiction'},
  {title: 'fiction'},
  {title: 'non-fiction'},
  {title: 'non-fiction'},
]
```

What I'd like to do is put together another array that counts the number of times a particular `title` occurs in the original array:

```js
const distilled = [
  {fiction: 2},
  {non-fiction: 3}
]
```

I'm sure I need to loop through the `tags` array, check `e.title` against the keys that currently exist in `distilled`, and if it's there, add to the value, versus if not, add it as an object with a value of 1.

Where I'm stumped is that second step, checking whether an object already exists in `distilled` with that specific key. It would be easy to use `Array.prototype.find()` if it was just an array of individual values. But since it's an array of objects, I'm not sure how to check that without looping through `distilled` again and again for each item in `tags` and looking for `hasOwnKey`.

There has to be some way with `.map()` or `.reduce()`, right? I'd appreciate any help

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. ***[Do some research](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+group+count+array+site:stackoverflow.com)***, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: @mplungjan Thank you! I completely forgot about the `object[key]` syntax in the second answer of the suggested duplicate.